# Delay execution of event up the 'event bubble order' until ajax call completes

Tags: jquery, wait, sleep, jquery-events, event-bubbling

EDIT: in response to comments about executing click event programaticaly on the anchor element, or using, window.open- I can't use these because of the popup blocker. 
I must allow the original mouseclick event on the anchor by the user to complete its course- resulting in an unblocked new window.

It seems like the best compromise here is to execute a synchronous ajax request- and present the user with a spinner gif until the request completes.

EDIT: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cXdJg/35/

Consider the case of a web editor with link to a player page.

on click of a link with href set to the player,
the editor checks if the content has been saved to the server:

if yes: do nothing.

if not: execute ajax request to save the content.
on end of the ajax call: allow the click event on the anchor element to continue; leading to execution of request for player page in new browser window.

how is it possible to delay end of the function that intercepts the click event on the anchor element until the ajax call ends, without freezing the browser?
see http://www.devcheater.com/#Conclusion

I checked http://ajaxpatterns.org/Submission_Throttling, but do not see how I can apply that example here.

example of the idea in code form:

```
$('a.play').click(function){
    if(!isSaved){
          save();  //saves the content and **sets isSaved to true**
    }
     while (!isSaved){
          //burn time until isSaved,  but don't freeze the browser!
     }
     //allow the event handler to end, after which the click on anchor element will
     //  load the player page in new window.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the link you posted (http://www.devcheater.com/#Conclusion) points to your biggest issue here: what you are specifically wanting to do doesn't appear to be possible. You could, however, try something like this (code reused from the JSFiddle):

This approach does not allow the `click` handler to return `true`, with the idea being that you would open the link from the `success` function. This uses `window.open`, so the popup will likely be blocked until the user has allowed it.

```
$('.wait').click(function(event){
    var $element = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'some_url',
        data: '',
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            $('.result').html("ajax call complete on "+ new Date().toTimeString());

            var href = $element.attr('href');

            if (typeof href != "undefined") {
                window.open(href);
            }                    
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The only other option here is to make a synchronous AJAX call, which would block the browser but would solve the popup-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the [jQuery.ajax **async**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '.....',
  async: false      //Here
});
```

Comment: The poster asked a way to do it without blocking the browser, async blocks the browser.

Comment: assuming I cant get this to work well with option 1 or 3 in the post above (queue or data) than this is a good, simple solution (with a compromise of blocking the browser until request completes, as mentioned above)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1**

Do you have control over the "Player" code? Instead of waiting for the data to be saved before opening the Player, **let the Player wait for the data to be ready.**

You could do like this:

As you get the click on the link and **isSaved** is false start immediately an AJAX **async** call to save the data an let the Player open in a new window.

The Player's link will have (on the URL) a parameter that will tell that the data is not ready (saving in progress). The Player will start querying the server (one async ajax call every a couple of seconds) for the "last version" os the data.

When saved data is ready it'll be served to the Player.

One important detail: it is fundamental that when the Player ask the server for the data, the last version of that data is provided.

To ensure this you have to generate a random number that will be the **key** to identify the last version of the data.

Pass the key along with the ajax call when you save the data. Pass it along with the URL that will invoke the Player. Again, the Player will pass the key to the server when queries the saved data.

More difficult to explain than to implement!

**Solution #2**

When the user make changes, disable the link, start saving and when saving is done enable the link again.

When the link is clicked **isSaved** will be always true.

--

Hope this helps..

Comment: sure, this would be great- but how do I load the player page in new window without being blocked by the popup blocker?

Comment: I missed the "popup blocker issue" in the question. I edit my answer.

Comment: thank you for the thoughtful responses. we thought of solution #1, but the cloud servers on azure are currently stateless (not using azure cache) so different servers may be handling the request. It may be too much overhead to save the last version key in the database. The data can be saved in html local storage and thus shared by two browser windows- but that may be overkill as well. regarding option #2 - its a possible compromise, and may be implemented if other routes prove undersireable

Comment: as for solution #2 I would say --easier is better--. if saving is fast, the button will stay dimmed for little time; it's not bas user interface

Answer (score 1):

As i see it you have a couple of options:

- You can look at the jQuery queue method which allows you to queue execution of function blocks to make them synchronous.
- A different approach could be to trigger the click event using `jQuery.trigger()` in the ajax complete handler. This would be the simplest solution if it doesn't matter if some event handlers are executed twice.
- Lastly you could extract all eventhandlers from the event using the `$('[href tag event trigger]').data('events')`, remove the eventhandler of the function in your current context and call the rest in your ajax complete handler of save.

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: thank you for the throughful response. I have considered option 1, and option 3 sounds intriguing- can I actually store the event handler that causes the new window to be opened, and activate it at the completion of the ajax call?

Comment: can you show an example of how to store the browser's native handler (the one that leads to navigation of the url in a new window), and activate this event in success function of the ajax call?   I assume I access it through $(this).data('events') within my javascript click handler on the anchor

Answer (score 1):

Add event listener for click and loaded and create associated event handlers in your  code.

```
// handles click
var handleClick = function(event){
var $element = $(this);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'some_url',
    data: '',
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function() {
        $('.result').trigger('loaded', $element.attr('href'));
    }
});

// Handles loaded state
var handleLoad = function(href){
    $(this).html('ajax call complete on '+ new Date().toTimeString());
    // your window is already loaded.
};

// create the event listeners
$(document).on('click', '.wait', handleClick);
$(document).on('loaded', '.result' handleLoad);
```

Comment: thanks Jani  for the complete example I will give this a try :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while( !isSaved )
$.delay(100);
```

Comment: Thanks. however, delay only works within the a certain context. I get undefined. I read the api http://api.jquery.com/delay/ currently  checking into how to implement $.delay  in this case.  appreciate any pointers.